# Extract data from json string with or without JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I've got the following json code stored in a java String:

`String str = {"posts":[{"key":"key1","value":"x"},{"key":"key2","value":"0"},{"key":"key3","value":"y"}]}`

Is there a way to extract the values from the string using `JSONObject` or should I use the old school method:

```
 String[] parts = str.split("\"");
```

In my case the values are stored in the array at the positions: `parts[9]`,  `parts[17]` and `parts[25]`. 
  It works well so far, but I wonder if I could use `JSONObject` for that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JSONObject` (from the `org.json` package, [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)), you can easily extract values.

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
final JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
final Collection<String> values = new ArrayList<>(posts.length());

for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
    final JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
    values.add(post.getString("value"));
}

// values = [x, 0, y]
```

I'd **absolutely avoid** any kind of manual `String` manipulation.

Comment: Thank you "LppEdd" for your answer. I am using your code now, but I had to change it to make it work for me. First, I encountered the following error: "'<>'operator is not allowed for source level bellow 1.7"... so I had to change the line like this: "final Collection<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(posts.length());" After that I realised that I don't know how to retreive data from that collection and I had to change the "Collection" to "List" like this: "final List<String> values  = new ArrayList<String>(posts.length());" ... Now, my  string values are: "values.get(0)..."

Comment: @DanielDaniel if you need other help, edit the answer and add the code you're working with now. I'll gladly take a look at it :)

Comment: Thanks! I am making a tiny woocommerce stock inventory android project, using the zxing library for a barcode scanner and my project it's allmost over. I just have to put all the "modules" or the classes with the methods together in the main project, becouse for this task I used 2 projects (1 for the barcode scanner and the second for the async classes for Json, php and mysql routines). I hope I won't need any help, other than I could get on "google" untill the end of the project, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson library provided by google if you are using Java

https://github.com/google/gson

Here you can convert your java to Json and Json back to java objects seamlessly.